# How to fix this test case: Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'dls-option'

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

This is my day 3 in Angular unit testing with Jasmine and Karma. I'm following Pluralsight lectures. First thing first, `dls-option` is a component which I'm using form a library. I'll explain. I'm using a library of angular components provided by our company. In the below code `<dls-dropdown>` and `<dls-option>` are nothing but `<select>` and `<option>` tag of HTML. They've created color and font styling wrapper around it. Here's my code:

**timeselector.component.html**

```
<div>
  <h1>Choose one from the list</h1>
  <dls-dropdown>
    <dls-option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [value]="mode">
      <p>{{ mode }}</p>
    </dls-option>
  </dls-dropdown>
 </div>
```

**timeselector.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ... } from '@angular/core';
...

@Component({
    selector: 'app-timeselector',
    templateUrl: './timeselector.component.html'
})
export class TimeselectorComponent implements OnInit {
    modes = ["Novice", "Intermediate", "Expert", "Beast"];
    ...
}
```

and here's my test file:
**timeselector.component.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from "@angular/core/testing"
import { TimeselectorComponent } from './timeselector.component'
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

fdescribe('TimeselectorComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TimeselectorComponent>;
    @Component({
        selector: 'dls-label',
        template: '<div></div>'
    })
    class DlsLabelComponent {}

    @Component({
        selector: 'dls-dropdown',
        template: '<div></div>'
    })
    class DlsDropdownComponent {}


    @Component({
        selector: 'dls-option',
        template: '<div></div>'
    })
    class DlsDropdownOption {}

    beforeEach(()=>{
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                FormsModule
            ],
            declarations: [
                TimeselectorComponent,
                DlsLabelComponent,
                DlsDropdownComponent,
                DlsDropdownOption
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TimeselectorComponent);
    })
    it('should create', ()=> {
        //expect(fixture.componentInstance).toBeTruthy();
    })
})
```

But my test case is failing. Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Please help me with this and also feel free to suggest other mistakes as well. This will help me in my career.

PS: I just want to do a shallow testing. I want to mock child components.

Comment: I think you are missing DlsDropdownModule import in your testbed beforeEach module imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error message is quite precise here - the `dls-options` mock component is missing `@Input() value`.

The `timeselector.component.html` is rendering `dls-option` and passing `mode` into its `value` input:

```html
<dls-option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [value]="mode">
```

So you'll need to create that input in your mock:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'dls-option',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
class DlsDropdownOption {
    @Input() value;
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Can you please explain a little bit more. Why and how it is working now.

Comment: Glad it did. The `timeselector.component.html` is saying that for each "mode" you want to render `dls-option` and pass that mode through its `[value]` input - hence Angular is expecting that the `dls-option` component has an input with the name "value". If Angular doesn't find such property on the `dls-option` class then it means there's a problem inside your code and Angular throws an error.